# ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript

I'm having a problem, whenever I try to remove an element from the array it gives this error #2025. The object is not visible on stage anymore when I click on it but it always gives this error.

```
//remove items  inventory 
    public function RemoveObject(mc:MovieClip)
    {
        var checkRemove:Number = curSlot - 1;
        trace("current slot " + (curSlot-1));
        trace("current pos array" + myIndex);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < itemS.length;i++)  {
            this.removeChild(itemS[checkRemove]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: do you want to remove one item ?

Answer (score 0):

do not use `for` just :

```
this.removeChild(itemS[checkRemove]);
```

Comment: it seems to remove object from stage now,

Comment: @TomJacobs is that what you want ?

Comment: yes it removes the object from screen with this code but  when I add the splice function the object doesn't remove anymore from screen

Comment: @TomJacobs you should add it after `this.removeChild(itemS[checkRemove]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to remove more than one items, Use for each loop because when ever you remove a child container would re-index other childs it contains.

```
for each (var child:DisplayObject in this.getChildren()) {
    this.removeChild(child);
}
```

and if you wants to remove only one item then it can be done as

```
this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(childIndex));
```

following methods of [Container](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#methodSummary) are also helpful to get desire child

```
getChildByName(name:String):DisplayObject
getChildIndex(child:DisplayObject):int
```

and its better to check first that child you are going to remove is in container or not

```
var child:DispalyObject = this.getChildAt(childIndex);

if(this.contains(child))
{
  this.removeChild(child);
}
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: it works now but
it seems to remove object from the stage now, though it doesn't remove the element from the array. When I use splice to remove the element from array it removes the same item as with removeChild
this is my function

itemS.splice(checkRemove,1);

Comment: Dear i am not Clear what you are saying, Please see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html, i recommend you to use ArrayCollection, a wrapper class around array it will give you methods like removeItemAt(index) to remove item from Array